# How to get customers who have most purchases in past 365 days, but none before?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble writing this sql query. Basically I need to find the top 100 sCompanys who had the most nSales within the last 365 days, but had zero sales before 365 days. This is being done in node so its a string, I am also passing in parameters. Start date is the date for 365 days ago.

This is not throwing any errors when I run it, however it also is not returning any data.

````
  getMostSales365NoneBefore(startDate) {
    let sqlQuery = '';

    sqlQuery =
      "SELECT TOP 100 SUM(nQuoteTotal) AS nSales, sCompany FROM Customer_Quotes WHERE (bDeleted=0 AND sStatus='Closed' AND dtFirstClosed > " +
      "'" +
      startDate +
      "')" +
      ' AND (nSales < ' +
      "'" +
      startDate +
      "') IS NOT NULL" +
      ' GROUP BY sCompany ORDER BY nSales DESC';

    console.log(sqlQuery);

    return sqlQuery;
  }, ```
````

Comment: I assume this is javascript in a browser?

Comment: Its a sql query in node, its passed to the npm package mssql

Comment: You are *not* passing in parameters, you are concatenating values in, and you should never do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should parameterize your query properly, and pass through `@startDate` as a parameter.**

Note that you cannot refer to aggregates in the `WHERE` part, only in the `HAVING`, `ORDER BY` or `SELECT`

The query you want would look like this

```sql
SELECT TOP (100)
    SUM(CASE WHEN dtFirstClosed >= @startDate THEN nQuoteTotal END) AS nSales,
    sCompany
FROM Customer_Quotes
WHERE bDeleted = 0
    AND sStatus = 'Closed'
GROUP BY sCompany
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN dtFirstClosed < @startDate THEN 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY nSales DESC
```